# Adjust Brightness of Image part

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am new to Matlab and to Image Processing as well, I know we can change image brightness by following formula if my image is `I`

```
newImg=imadjust(I, [low_in high_in], [low_out,high_out]);
```

it adjust all pixel's value of image but how can I do it on some part of image, like I detected face in the image now I want change its brightness how can I do it using `imadjust`.

**Edit**

I have detected area in a binary mask.

**I done it please see the answer and also the reference in the answer.**

Comment: Do you have a binary mask of the area that you want to apply `imadjust` to?

Comment: yes I got mask, mask has same size as size of image.

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz this is handled at http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/_f19-12807.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I done it,

Well I wanted to change the brightness of some area of the image, the area which I wanted was calculated by a binary mask `mask`, So I did, First I simply change the brightness of my input Image `I`, and store the result in `newImg` like this

```
newImg = imadjust(I, [low_in high_in], [low_out,high_out]);
```

then apply mask on my orignal image and store value of masked area of `newImg` like this

```
I(mask) = newImg (mask);
```

[Reference](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/59354-adjust-brightness-of-image-part#answer_71807)

I think its informative and not to bore anyone, If you guys wont motivate me then I cant learn, as people closed [my thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435445/detecting-face-points-in-an-image) just because I was asking questions, and I am using same database of Image for different type of projects.

Answer (score 1):

```
%Suppose these are the coordinates of the rectangle in which the face is detected%
%You can do the following to adjust the brightness of that region

topLeft = 10;
topRight = 50;
bottomLeft = 50;

newImg = I;
newImg(topLeft:bottomLeft,topLeft:topRight) = imadjust(newImg(topLeft:bottomLeft,topLeft:topRight), [low_in high_in], [low_out,high_out]);
```

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz that code is directly adjusted to a rectangle. Are you saying you don't have a rectangle either ? That is quite a weird face you got.

Comment: I have detected whole person in an image like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cSwzj.jpg), I detected it using some mask, I have this mask in logical, so now I want to change its brightness